# Removing new lines in R

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to bring multiple rows into one cell in my CSV file. I first began with converting my text file into a CSV file, however the final column needs to have all the contents in one cell, and it's currently being split into multiple. The CSV File currently looks like the first picture, and needs to look like the second picture. [Picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z7oa.png)[Picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jg53.png)

I have the following code:

```
  mydata = read.table ("rolled_swiftmessage_test.txt", sep="|", allowEscapes 
  = TRUE, fill = FALSE)

  write.table(mydata, file="rolled_swiftmessage_test.csv",sep=",",col.names= 
  FALSE,row.names= FALSE)
```

Currently it produces Picture_1, and I need it to produce picture_2. How do I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Use `write.csv` to write .csv rather than `write.table` because it passes the correct default arguments. Can you provide an example of what your .txt file looks like before you try to read it in?

Comment: ID|Country|City|Name|Message
1|USA|NYC|John Smith|{Hi:
 |   |   |          |My:
 |   |   |          |Name:
 |   |   |          |Is:
 |   |   |          |John}

Comment: Sorry the pasting is not in a correct format, but basically the message is split apart by colons vertically

Comment: Forgive me, but how are the two pictures different? They look exactly the same to me.

Comment: Your text file is not properly delimited. You have a bunch of white-space characters between the string parts. Ideally I'd recommend starting with cleaner source data, otherwise it will probably take a combination of Regex/sub expressions to fix it.

Comment: Yes I'm aware its not properly delimited, therefore I try to delimit it in the CSV, and combine the last message column into one cell. Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

After corresponding with the OP and seeing the kind of data that she has, this is my updated answer:

```
mydata <- read.table ("Test_TextFile.txt", sep="|", allowEscapes = TRUE, fill = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = F)

# Remove rows full of dashes
for(row in 1:nrow(mydata)) {
  if(grepl('^\\-+$', mydata$V1[row])) mydata <- mydata[-row,]
}

empty_rows <- which(grepl('^\\s*$', mydata$V1))
rows_to_squeeze <- split(empty_rows, cumsum(c(1, diff(empty_rows) != 1)))

for(i in length(rows_to_squeeze):1) {
  mydata$V12[rows_to_squeeze[[i]][1] - 1] <- paste(mydata$V12[seq(rows_to_squeeze[[i]][1] - 1, rows_to_squeeze[[i]][length(rows_to_squeeze[[i]])])], collapse = ' ')
  mydata <- mydata[-seq(rows_to_squeeze[[i]][1], rows_to_squeeze[[i]][length(rows_to_squeeze[[i]])]),]
}

write.table(mydata, file="rolled_swiftmessage_test.csv", sep=",", col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
```

**Original answer**

Here you have my attempt at this. It's not pretty, but I think it works. Basically, I read the file as lines of text, not a table, I operate on the lines to join those that belong on the same 'message' cell, and then I put them in a nice data frame that can be saved as a csv file. Let me know if you need any other tweaks:

```
install.packages('stringr') ## if not installed yet
library(stringr) ## in order to use str_detect and str_split below

mydata <- readLines("rolled_swiftmessage_test.txt")

new_mydata = vector('character')
current <- 1
while(!is.na(mydata[current])) {
  if(str_detect(mydata[current], '\\{')) {
    i <- 1
    while(!str_detect(mydata[current + i], '\\}')) {
      mydata[current] <- paste(mydata[current], mydata[current + i], collapse = ' ')
      i = i + 1
    }
    mydata[current] <- paste(mydata[current], mydata[current + i], collapse = ' ')
    mydata[current] <- gsub('\\| \\| \\| \\|', '', mydata[current])
    new_mydata = c(new_mydata, mydata[current])
    current = current + i + 1  
  } else {
    new_mydata = c(new_mydata, mydata[current])
    current = current + 1
  }
}

new_mydata <- sapply(new_mydata, function(x) str_split(x, '\\|'))
new_mydata <- as.data.frame(t(as.data.frame(new_mydata)))

write.table(new_mydata, file="rolled_swiftmessage_test.csv", sep=",", col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
```

The resulting image after opening the csv file (notice that I added the same row to the original text file three times just so that I would have more lines for testing):

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Howevever I am getting the error "Error: could not find function 'str_detect'" would you know why?

Comment: Oh, sorry. You need to install and load the `stringr` package for that to work. I'll edit the post now.

Comment: Got it, I downloaded that...now I'm getting another error. "Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 12, 221"

Comment: Does that happen when you try to `write.table` at the end? I think the problem might be that your original `.txt` file is different than mine. Can you post the file, or at least the first few rows, to make sure that the script is doing the right thing?

Comment: yes it happens when I do the write.table at the end. Here is the first row of my text file: Field 1       |Field 2|Field 3|   Field 4|Field 5|Field 6|Field 7|Field 8|Field 9|Field 10|Field 11|Message Text
--------------|---|-|----------|------------|------------|---|---|---|---|---|-------------------------------------------------------------------
ABC789827461|87987967786|SDOIFJAFDIJ|        -1|           0|         524|ISDFOIAJ|SAWFG|SDIFJSDF|98887656567|HIUHSF|{1:AOIDSFOIJANFOIAJOI}{2:O10117RESC1156N}{3:{1456:1234567}}{4:

Comment: Hmm... this looks quite different from what you posted above. Here it looks like the different parts of the 'message' are not separated from each other by vertical bars |, whereas the line you posted as a comment to your question did have the bars between them (for instance, four bars between My: and Name:) My whole code was based on what you posted before, so of course it doesn't work. It's really hard to do this if I don't have the data. Could you paste at least the first 5 lines as code in your question, or send me the text file as an attachment to oriol at oriol dot codes?

Comment: sure I will email you.

Comment: Did you receive my email?

Comment: Yes, and I just wrote back.

Comment: Hi Oriol I just sent a new email with a new file

Comment: Hi Oriol, I just sent another email with a new question. Thanks!